# How do I build a view in Interface Builder then interact with it later programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a view that I don't necessarily want embedded in a view controller, which seems to be the necessity with storyboards. It's complex, so it would be easiest to create it in Interface Builder.

Is there a function in Xcode to build a view controller in Interface Builder but not really associate it a storyboard and only use it when you need it? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes why not. You need to do the followings

1. Create .h/.m class of type UIView.
2. Create UserInterface file with a view, you can design it the way you want.
3. Assign the Class Name of View in nib to the class you have created in step 1.
4. Create all you IBOutlet not assigned to the File Owner, but the View in the XIB.
5. Use the following code to use the view anywhere independently

   YourClass *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourView Nib Name" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];

Comment: You are creating UIView class there, you need to create User Interface separately. See here http://i.imgur.com/0cwpedF.png The option you are looking for it only available for UIViewControllers

Comment: Ah, I see. Do you have any idea why I can't update the objects, though? I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823944/why-can-i-not-manipulate-the-objects-in-my-xib-file