# Why can I not manipulate the objects in my xib file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xib, nib

I've got a file, `View.xib` with three `UIView`s in it, each of the same UIView subclass. The views all look a bit different, but they're going to be used as pages in a tutorial screen, so they have page indicators on the bottom.

I made an outlet collection of the three page indicators on each page. So in the custom `UIView` I made an outlet collection, and for each of the three views I connected all three page indicators to the outlet collection.

However, in `initWithFrame:` I do the following:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        for (UIView *pageIndicator in self.pageIndicators) {
            pageIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = pageIndicator.bounds.size.width / 2;
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

(The for loop being the key part.)

But when I add the `UIView` from the nib in my other file, the indicators are not rounded as the above code should accomplish:

```
    TutorialScreen *tutorialScreen1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    tutorialScreen1.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
    [self.notificationWindow addSubview:tutorialScreen1];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Sample project where it doesn't work: http://cl.ly/170O2u10181V

Comment: You should move your code from `initWithCoder` to `awakeFromNib` initializer, the answer below is correct.

Answer (score 3):

When an object is read from a nib/xib, it is initialized with `initWithCoder:`. Override that and do the same thing (or, better yet, move it to a method that both call).

```
- (void)mySetup
{
    for (UIView *pageIndicator in self.pageIndicators) {
        pageIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = pageIndicator.bounds.size.width / 2;
    }
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self mySetup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self mySetup];
    }
    return self;
}
```

After looking at your project, you're suffering from a different problem. You didn't mention you were trying to use IBOutlets. :) IBOutlets are not loaded before `initWithCoder:`. You'll need to trap `awakeFromNib` instead.

From Apple's docs:

> The nib-loading infrastructure sends an `awakeFromNib` message to each object recreated from a nib archive, but only after all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an object receives an `awakeFromNib` message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and action connections already established.

You'd do so like this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    for (UIView *circle in self.circles) {
        circle.layer.cornerRadius = circle.bounds.size.width / 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, they still appear square.